# Facebook app-scoped id digits only?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is facebook app-scoped id digits only? As im working on to be able to login with username or fb-login, and im planning to store username and fb-id in same column which is login, so if facebook app-scoped id is digits only, i will force usernames to be at least contains 1 alphabet to avoid duplication and inteference from app-scoped id

Comment: With Graph API v2.0 and above, you cannot get the username anymore.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user), the Facebook ID is a "numeric string". That seems to indicate that it does indeed contain only digits. Personally, I've never seen anything other than digits, and although it's theoretically possible for the API to change in the future, it's probably unlikely that they would change this particular thing.

So, your plan should work.